# Нужна помощь с php классом

Tags: php

Решил использовать класс https://habrahabr.ru/post/165069/
Но не получается элементарно сделать update.
Делаю запрос:

```
$data = array('domainid'=> $domainid, 'name'=> $name, 'meta'=> $meta, 'html'=> $html, 'active'=> $active);
$sql = "INSERT INTO versions SET  ?u
WHERE name= ?s";
$db->query($sql,$data,$name);
```

При таком запросе получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SafeMySQL: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE name= 'Основная
>   версия'' at line 2.

Подскажите как корректно сделать запрос update?

Comment: чем `PDO` не угодил?

Comment: @mix, хочу упросить основной код, и не проверять get Запросы а сразу их записывать

Comment: Одно другому не мешает, это во-первых, а во-вторых, `INSERT` запрос не может содержать `WHERE`. В этом и ошибка вашей задачи.

Comment: Читайте мануал! В вашем случае, `$data` должна быть строкой, а не массивом(**?u («update») — набор значений для SET (строка вида `field`='value',`field`='value')**). `UPDATE` делается также, как и `INSERT`. Перепишите свой код, основываясь на мануал и тогда должно работать.

Comment: @SdafsFasafs В insert не бывает `SET`, там есть `VALUES`. Полезно перечислять явно после имени таблицы имена колонок, на случай если потом колонка добавится или по какой то причине в какой то системе порядок колонок в таблице окажется иным. И в insert не бывает `where`

Comment: @mix посчитай, сколько кода понадобится написать на PDO, и сразу станет понятно - чем.

Comment: @Ипатьев `$db->query("INSERT INTO versions SET  domainid= '$domainid', name='$name', meta='$meta', html='$html', active='$active'");` Считай сам и сверь со своим ответом.

Comment: @mix честно говоря, *такого* чудовищного ответа я не ожидал. Вопросов больше не имею.

Comment: @Ипатьев ок, мой ответ чудовищный, только объясни почему, чтобы я больше не повторял такой *чудовищной* ошибки.

Comment: @mix http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы корректно сделать запрос update, **надо написать в запросе слово update.** А не insert.

```
$data = array('domainid'=> $domainid, 'name'=> $name, 'meta'=> $meta, 'html'=> $html, 'active'=> $active);
$sql = "UPDATE versions SET ?u WHERE name= ?s";
$db->query($sql,$data,$name);
```